# Accessing custom component property at runtime to set value after render the component

Tags: javascript, angular, dom, components

I am working on Angular application. My requirement is, lets take a page and custom component. My custom component has 3 inputs and I have bind the custom component tag in my page HTML.

```
<my-column [setInfo]="info" [disabled]="" [inspectRequired]="'true'"></my-column>
```

The above mentioned component rendered at the time page loading initially. After that, at one point of time I need to pass the value to the attribute [disabled] from my class(programmatically). How I can access this my own component property and set the value at runtime using DOM ? Solutions are most welcome. Thanks in advance.

Comment: from what I understand you could create a subject and pass it to your main component through a service. Not sure to cell understand the question but still I you could add more code; Thanks in advance

Comment: Yes. I need to pass input via disabled property to my-column component class from the page component at runtime.

Comment: but this could be done without DOM why is DOM so important. I mean when loaded you'll have to deal programtically with ts file not the html I guess

Comment: do you want to go for a chat . still from what I understand you could do an array of `Subject` ans use `*ngFor`. As I told you before it would be nice to have the context of your code. Another user answered to your question is that what you meant ? changing input directly on the DOM inspector?

Comment: I've added a change in my answer

Answer (score 0):

you could do something like this I guess even if I'm not sure to get the whole context of your code. Here is for a single column component you'll have to dynamically create subjects with `push()` and `splice()` for example.

main.ts

```
...
disabled = false;
...

ngAfterViewInit(){
 this.disabled = true;
}
```

main.html

```
<my-column [setInfo]="info" [disabled]="disabled" [inspectRequired]="'true'">
```

now if you want to change input of `main.html` when `my-column` is loaded I recommend you to suscribe to a `Subject` shared via a service injected into both components.

in your main html this would do something like

```
<div *ngFor="let i of index; col of columns;">
    <my-column [setInfo]="info" [disabled]="mySubjectService.mySubject[i] | async" [inspectRequired]="'true'">
</div
```

Comment: But I need to access dynamically. My form is totally dynamic approach. There is a change to use my-column component more than one time in my form. In the each tag I set id to get the DOM programmatically. Using the DOM, I need to set the input. So that I can set the input to the appropriate component If my-column component placed more than one time.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by using a chrome browser extension called [Augury](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/augury/elgalmkoelokbchhkhacckoklkejnhcd)

After installing it, open chrome dev tools (ctrl + shift + I)

click the Augury tab as shown in the screenshot below

[image]

1. click on the Augury tab
2. click on the particular component whose properties you want to change from the DOM tree
3. change the value